# how coefficient of series representation of two entire functions having same set of infinite zeros is related?

Tags: complex-analysis

According to the Weierstrass factorization theorem, an entire function can be represented as a product involving its zeroes. If the number of zeros is infinite, the expansion has the following form $f(z) = z^me^{\phi(z)}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\tfrac{z}{u_n}\right)$ (assuming the canonical product representation and rank of the canonical product zero). So, if two entire functions (say $f(z)$ and $g(z)$) have the same set of infinite zeros then they will only differ by the form of $\phi(z)$ and $m$ in the product representation. Instead of product representation if we use series representation (which is always possible for entire function) how the coefficient of series representation of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ will be related with each other?

Comment: How is the series for $\,f(z):=e^{\phi(z)}\,$ related to the series for $f(z):=1$? They both are entire non-zero functions.

Comment: The motivation behind the question is that how one can extract the information given by the product representation through series representation.